# How could I derive the Taylor series for $e^{-z^2}$ about $z_0=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I wanted to know how one could get the Taylor series for $e^{-z^2}$ without using the Taylor series for $e^x$ and then substituting. Is it possible to proceed using trig functions?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Taylor series of $\cos(z), \sin(z)$?  If not, the transformation doesn't gain anything.

On the other hand, if you are allowed to write
$$
e^{-z^2} = {1 \over e^{z^2}} = {1 \over 1 + \mbox{(the rest of the Taylor series of $e^{z^2}$)}},
$$
then Chapter 1 of [Cartan's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=SlpwANmq5xQC&source=gbs_navlinks_s) will teach you how to calculate the series of the resulting expression.

Comment: You don't want to do it the easy way? Of course, $e^{(iz)^2}\ne(\cos(z) + i\sin(z))^2$.